# Creating Scroll in splitpanel or tablelayoutpanel in C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, windows-forms-designer

[image: Using tablelayoutPanel]

[image: Result of tablelayoutPanel: My labels go out of the screen when i dock them at bot]

[image: Using Splitpanel]

[image: Result of Split Panel:Messages are overflowed but not creating scroll]

- 1st image :Using tablelayoutPanel
- 2nd image :Result of tablelayoutPanel: My labels go out of the screen
  when i dock them at bot
- 3rd image :Using Splitpanel
- 4th image :Result of Split Panel:Messages are overflowed but not
  creating scroll

So i am creating a BOT that responds according the user's question while doing it,i am creating two labels one which print user's question on the right and print respond of BOT at left side, while doing it i want scroll as the panel go overflow but unfortunately or maybe lack of my approach i cant do it while docking label at the bottom 
here is the code of my labels 
(i am new to c# kindly ignore childish stuff)

LEFT SIDE (BOT):

```
Label label = new Label();
        label.Size = new Size(35, 20);
        label.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8F);
        label.Text = "IceFrog : I am unable to understand you try expressing in other way";
        label.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No;
        splitContainer1.Panel1.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No;
        //label.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        // label.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        label.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(label);
```

RIGHT SIDE (human):

```
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Size = new Size(35, 20);
        label.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8F);
        label.Text = "Human : "+textBox1.Text;
        label.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No;
        splitContainer1.Panel2.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No;
        label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomRight;
        //label.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        // label.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        label.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(label);
```

Comment: I am unable to understand you try

Comment: Kidding aside, do you think it might be more natural for the Human side to be on the left?  (left-to-right reading)

Comment: i m trying to make scroll on panel overflow and cant approach it with both methods

Comment: i wanted to go with the chat box type stuff where your message appears at the right and sender's message at the left :3

Comment: You don't want to use a Label control for this.  Use a Read-Only TextBox or RichTextBox control instead.

Comment: As @LarsTech said, a couple of `RichTextBox` controls will solve the scrolling problem, because it's automatically triggered when needed and appending a line to the text will also scroll to the last line. You can also use different colors for the text if needed.

Comment: sorry for not explaining my problem properly but i was talking about the panel overflow i am trying to acquire scroll on panel as the messages go out of the panel

Comment: Pretty sure we understood the problem.  Pretty sure the problem is resolved by using a RIchTextBox control.

Comment: can you help me with the code if you don't mind ?
            var msg = new RichTextBox
            {
                Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8F),
                Text = @"Human : " + textBox1.Text,
                Multiline = true,
                WordWrap = true,
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
                ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None,
                Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
                ReadOnly = true,
                SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right
            };
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(msg);

Comment: You append text to a RichTextBox, `msg.AppendText(textBox1.Text);`  You want to scroll the contents, but you are setting the ScrollBars to None.  Not what you want.

Comment: Thankyou for your help mate problem is solved ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `AutoScrollMinSize` for each pannel

```
this.splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(1, 0);
this.splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(1, 0);
```

Alternatively, you can do the same using the designer

[image]

To keep newly added items visible (at the bottom) add those lines to your codes

```
 splitContainer1.Panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = splitContainer1.Panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
 splitContainer1.Panel2.VerticalScroll.Value = splitContainer1.Panel2.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
```

Comment: Thankyouu sooo much @L_J .My heart just keeps thanking you and thanking you ^^